# multiple slashes in url

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

How can I make an HTTP 301 redirect with PHP from http://example.com///xyz/// to http://example.com/xyz/

I'm using nginx and I know that it's possible to do it with nginx config, but it makes infinity redirect loop for cyrillic paths.
This is my nginx config

```
set $test_uri $scheme://$host$request_uri;
if ($test_uri != $scheme://$host$uri$is_args$args) {
 rewrite ^ $scheme://$host$uri$is_args$args? permanent;
}
```

I also know that PHP $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] won't contain any extra slashes so I can't use it for my situation.

Comment: The arguments are missing in $test_uri

Comment: This is example config, I`m using correct one. I'm sure it's correct, because latin urls works well.

Comment: Nginx should take care of such multiple slashes by itself without any intervention from you. However you should fix your application and stop generating such

Comment: Thank you for reply. It's not my application generating such URL`s. I need it for SEO purposes, to make sure no duplicate content are received by search engines.